# Get an object value in jquery or javascript and makes a post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Well my problem is like this, lets take an example. There are 30 links in a page, and under each link there is a like button. And when someone clicks a like button the link get liked via an ajax post request to a php file.

But is it possible by using jquery or javascript to write a single set of code that will find which link was liked (by getting an ID or something of the link) and then send it to the php via ajax request, rather than writing 30 lines of ajax post request for each link being liked. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: @MohammadAdil well i was thinking of writing 20 ajax requests, but it's ugly and inefficient. Is there a way to handle all 20 cliks via one ajax request? I mean the variable is the link that is being clicked everything is the same, if there is a way to get the link id or something else to the ajax script then it'll work i guess

Comment: At Least , you can show us the link with the value you want to access

Comment: @MohammadAdil Doh. I tagged the wrong person. Haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can associate each link with the its button by using a `data-*` attribute. On your button, use `data-mylink="linkId"` and give it the link's id.

Then, on your onclick you can do something like this:

```
$('.buttonClass').on('click', function(){
    var myLinkId = $(this).attr('data-mylink'); 
    //as David Barker suggested, you can also grab it with $(this).data('mylink')
    //whatever else you have to do.
});
```

Alternatively, you could also wrap them both in a div and do:

```
$('.buttonClass').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('a').text() or .val() or .attr('href');
});
```

### Edit

As War10ck pointed out, if your items are created dynamically, you'll want to delegate with:

```
$(document).on('click', '.buttonClass', function () { 
    // your code here 
});
```

What this says is: **use this click for any button that exists with `class="buttonClass"` or any button created later on with `class="buttonClass"`.**

Comment: As it's a data attribute `$(this).data('mylink')` would be more "jQuery'ish"

Comment: @DavidBarker is there any performance difference, do you know? I always use attr out of habit.

Comment: I like this solution. It's clean and simple. One thing to be mindful of though is whether any of these buttons are added dynamically. In that case you're solution would still work very well with a minor alteration to the `.on` event to make it a delegated event like so `$(document).on('click', '.buttonClass', function () { // your code here });`. Very clean cut though. +1

Comment: @War10ck agreed. But as he mentioned having to write 30 statements, I was under the impression they were already created.

Comment: @Yatrix Oh definitely. Sorry I wasn't meaning that to be rude or anything. My apologies if it came across that way. Just an alternative since the OP didn't clearly state what he/she wanted. :)

Comment: @War10ck No offense taken. I added it to my answer as it's a very good point. I was agreeing with ya. =)

Comment: @Yatrix primarily no, it uses the `.attr()` methods on first call however by using `.data` is it then cached and will be much faster to access.

Comment: @DavidBarker Good info...that'll I'll probably forget and use attr out of habit. But still good info! Thanks.

Comment: @Yatrix to be strictly correct it doesnt actually use `.attr` just a similar approach. I couldn't say on first load whether it would be faster or not without running tests on it... I can say for sure subsequent calls to it would be much faster.

Comment: @Yatrix Yah well although I mentioned 30 i was also thinking about adding more things after that dynamically. So thanks for War10ck for pointing that out. The answer is really helpful and will solve my problem. Thanks a log guys :) btw who down voted the question :/

Comment: @War10ck Yes I was thinking of adding more content dynamically thanks for pointing that out and :) it really helped me a lot :)

Comment: @Rukshan I didn't down-vote it, but it was probably down-voted since you didn't provide any code that shows you tried something on your own.

Comment: @Yatrix well i mean it's not a necessary to give the code isn't it? I mean i just had the rough idea that's it's possible but didn't know how to execute it. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @Rukshan It wasn't necessary to answer your question, but we always like to see that you tried it first. It's cool, though. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of problem I use to solve developing web-application. 
You can use `data-*` attributes like @Yatrix was saying or you can bind `.data()` to your buttons. 
I prefer the second way. I guess you're rendering these buttons through a template or dynimically , so you can use `.data('foo','bar')` then retrieve this through `$(this).data('foo')` (where `$(this)` refers to the button) , then take this data and send it via AJAX. These are identical way to solve this problems, but the only difference is that the second is not visible to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this in straight javascript. I haven't tested this though, so it might not be 100% correct.

HTML:

```
<a href="page-to-be-liked1.html">Link</a>
<div class="like-button" data-likeID="1">Button</div>

<a href="page-to-be-liked2.html">Link</a>
<div class="like-button" data-likeID="2">Button</div>

<a href="page-to-be-liked3.html">Link</a>
<div class="like-button" data-likeID="3">Button</div>

<a href="page-to-be-liked4.html">Link</a>
<div class="like-button" data-likeID="4">Button</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("like-button");
var post_to = '/location-of-php-script.php';

for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', buttonClick);
}

function buttonClick(event){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", post_to, true);
    request.send('likeID='+this.getAttribute('data-likeID'));
}
```